# Windows server 2008 >Raid 5 >How to check disk alignment

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

I wonder how to check if the alignment is correct in a soft raid 5 configuration of 3 disks/9tb running windows server 2008. Formatting and partitioning was done through the gui but there is no way I can verify if the system has aligned disk> os> >volumes via the gui.
Any command line magic to reveal this?

Comment: Hardware or software RAID?

Comment: Is this installed on physical local disks? Or some sort of remote disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start diskpart from a command prompt

execute "list disk"

execute "select disk X"

execute "list partition"

Comment: This is how it looks. Does it look aligned to you?

Comment: Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset   DISK 1
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    System             200 MB    20 KB
Partition 2    Dynamic Data      2794 GB   200 MB
Partition 3    Dynamic Reserved  1024 KB  2794 GB
Partition 4    Reserved           127 MB  2794 GB